# Have MVC4 main site authenticate for web application/virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, webforms

I have an MVC4 (using razor) main site and then an asp.net webforms store that runs as a web application in a virtual directory.  Can I have a forms authentication page in my MVC4 main site, authenticate the user and then upon authentication send them to the store AND if they try to browse directly to the virtual directory without yet being authenticated have it redirect them back to the MVC4 forms authentication page?

So for instance:
They go to www.mysite.com/account/login wherein it displays my nice log-in page running on MVC4 and part of the main site.
After they successfully log-in it takes them to www.mysite.com/store/ (a web application/virtual directory) and since they've successfully authenticated it displays the store.
And then on the flip site, if they're NOT YET authenticated and try to go directly to www.mysite.com/store/ (the web application/virtual directory) it redirects them back to the main site's forms authentication page at: www.mysite.com/account/login

I have it authenticating the user just fine on my MVC4 forms authentication page (I've tested this and verified it works), the problem is that when I then redirect them to the store, the store doesn't see them as logged in and asked them to log in using the forms authentication page that the store contains (which has been built in web parts).  I want to use the forms log-in page on my MVC4 site (as it's pretty looking and easier to control/update/code, etc).

Is this a session issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, I had read that before when researching this and it's a GREAT article with a WEALTH of knowledge in it... but it kind of took me in a different direction.

I finally ended up finding the exact solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316/1620286) on StackOverflow.

And also found some good info in another article over at CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6586/Single-sign-on-across-multiple-applications-in-ASP).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to use Forms Authentication across applications.

SO post [How to do Forms Authentication Across Applications in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944676/how-to-do-forms-authentication-across-applications-in-asp-net-mvc) should be helpful.